# custom iterator for a collection interface

Tags: c++, interface, iterator, generic-programming

I have an interface *ICollection* implementing a collection *ArdalanCollection* like this:

```
template <typename T>
class ICollection
{
public:
    virtual void add(T*) = 0;
    virtual T* get(int) = 0;
    virtual int count() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class ArdalanCollection :public ICollection<T>
{
public:
    ArdalanCollection() {
        index = 0;
    };
    virtual void add(T* obj) {
        encapsolateImplementation.insert(make_pair(index++, obj));
    };
    virtual T* get(int index) {
        return encapsolateImplementation[index];
    };
    virtual int count() {
        return encapsolateImplementation.size();
    };
private:
    int index;
    unordered_map < int, T* > encapsolateImplementation;
};
```

what I want is to have a generic iterator in *ICollection* interface which can loop all over the internal container elements(I haven't decided to choose unordered_map as my internal container I might change it to boost or something else). I want to use it in this way:

```
    Node *node1 = new Node(1, 0, 0, 0);
    Node *node2 = new Node(1, 0, 0, 0);
    ICollection<Node> *nodes = new ArdalanCollection<Node>();
    nodes->add(node1);
    nodes->add(node2);
    for (it=nodes->iterator.begin(); it < nodes->iterator.end(); it++) {

    }
```

Comment: Mixing templates with virtual functions is code smell.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0):

First your for loop idiom is not correct. It should rather look like

```
for(auto it = nodes->begin(); it != nodes->end(); it++)
```

then something along:

```
template <typename T, typename MyMap>
class ICollection
{
public:
    typedef typename MyMap<int, T *>::iterator iterator;
    virtual void add(T*) = 0;
    virtual T* get(int) = 0;
    virtual int count() = 0;
};
```

should be fine.